# Does C# guarantee evaluation order of branched nested expressions?

Tags: c#, expression, specifications, evaluation

C# handles both nested and chained expressions, obviously.
If the nesting and/or chaining is linear then it's evident what order the expressions are evaluated in:

`Foo(Bar(Baz().Bop()))` can **only** evaluate in the following order:

- `Baz()`
- `Bop()`
- `Bar()`
- `Foo()`

But what if the nesting *isn't* linear? Consider: `Foo(Baz()).Bar(Bop())`

Clearly the following MUST all be true:

- `Baz` before `Foo`
- `Foo` before `Bar`
- `Bop` before `Bar`

But it's not clear exactly when `Bop` will be evaluated.
Any of the following would be a viable order:

- Possibility #1

  - `Bop()`
  - `Baz()`
  - `Foo()`
  - `Bar()`
- Possibility #2

  - `Baz()`
  - `Bop()`
  - `Foo()`
  - `Bar()`
- Possibility #3

  - `Baz()`
  - `Foo()`
  - `Bop()`
  - `Bar()`

My instinct is that the 3rd option is likely correct. i.e. that it will fully evaluate `Foo(Baz())` before it starts to evaluate *any* of `.Bar(Bop())`

Whilst I could certainly test an individual situation to see what happens, that doesn't tell me whether my guess will *always* be true?

But my question is:
**Is the order of evaluation of branched nested expressions defined as part of the C# language specification, or left to the situational judgement of the compiler?**

If not, is it at least known to be deterministic?

Comment: Obvious comment: If your code ever *cares* about the answer to this question ... then your code is *very* likely to be poorly written! But that doesn't make the question any less valid or interesting :D

Comment: How should `Bar` ever be called, when `Foo` did not yet terminate? There is no indstance on which to call `Bar`, unless `Foo` has been executed.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Read the examples again. It's not about calling `Bar` before `Foo`, it's about calling `Bop` before `Foo`, or before `Baz`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'll find the answers in [Section 11 of the specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions).

Specifically, [11.6.6 Function member invocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1166-function-member-invocation) says:

> The run-time processing of a function member invocation consists of the following steps, where `M` is the function member and, if `M` is an instance member, `E` is the instance expression:
> ...
>
> - `E` is evaluated. If this evaluation causes an exception, then no further steps are executed.
> - The argument list is evaluated as described in §11.6.2.

So, given an expression `E.M(A)`, `E` is fully evaluated before `A` is evaluated.

For the `Foo(Baz()).Bar(Bop())` case, if we're looking at the evaluation of `Bar` (so `E` is `Foo(Baz())`, `M` is `Bar` and the argument list is `Bop()`), this means that `Foo` (`E`) must have been fully evaluated before `Bop` (the argument list) is evaluated, meaning that "possibility #3" is the correct one.

There's also [11.6.2.3 Run-time evaluation of argument lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#11623-run-time-evaluation-of-argument-lists):

> During the run-time processing of a function member invocation (§11.6.6), the expressions or variable references of an argument list are evaluated in order, from left to right

So in the expression `M(A, B)`, `A` is fully evaluated before `B` is evaluated.

Comment: Also see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070814-00/?p=25593 - everything is always left-to-right (unless the precedence of operators states otherwise, e.g. * before + for numerical calculations)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Even so, the order of evaluation is independent of the precedence, and is still always left-to-right. [See here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwAEAmARgFgAoaosgTgAoBBRgSgAIBqDgIXY4AqDgGF2bANzVaZJBwCWeDB1acA3hzpMARM22TNAdg5kJHAL4y5i5f3WaGjbb31mixkmctU61paIENLScRVyMOAGYvIA=)

Comment: Sorry yes, the article I linked actually states that. I should have said "even if the precedence of operators states otherwise".